# Bootstrap collapse stopped working - "blinking" Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I had bootstrap collapse (`bootstrap-transition.js v2.2.1`) working in my rails project working and now it blinks. The scenario is the page loads, I click a button to open the inner-collapse, which works fine, then when I click to close it it blinks and stays expanded.

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info offset3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Show completed</button><br>
  <div class="pull-left offset2 collapse" id="demo">
    <ul class="task-list" id="completed">
       <table>
         <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td><%= render "completed" %></td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>   
       </table>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

js on page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#demo").collapse("hide");
</script>
```

There has been some additional AJAX work on this view, but my question is what are my checks?
I have spent about 2 days on this problem checking everything I think it could be to no avail so finally I need to ask for help. When I try to implement collapse on any page it does the same blinking.

```
bootstrap.js and bootsrap.css.scs 2.2.1, rails 3.2.8
```

What am I overlooking? Thanks for your attention and for taking a look.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "blinks"?  Also, can you provide all of the JS on the page?